# Is it possible to write (or firstly, open) a disk file in two different programs simultaneously?

Tags: c, file-io

I need to update a log file according to the messages produced by two different modules which may be running simultaeously.

So is it possible to open and write a file simultaneously in two programs?

Sys Spec: SLES 11 x86_64.

Comment: It depends. Some operating systems allows programs to lock parts of a file. There is, however, no standard C functionality to help you with this.

Comment: As always when accessing shared resources concurrently, synchronising access keeps you from getting undefined results.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : I forgot to mention, I am working on SLES 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

- Use `flock()` (or a similar mechanism) to synchronize the writes on the open file descriptors (as already answered).
- Use `open()` and `close()` (or similar) repeatedly on systems that support (or even enforce) exclusive `open()`.
- Depend on buffered output to send out log lines uninterrupted. This is often used with *stderr* logging, as a possible race condition isn't usually a problem here.
- Use a logging service and only `open()` the file there. Other processes communicate with the logging service via IPC. You can use a custom logging service or a tool like `syslog` or `journald`. Both of them AFAIK support logging from non-root processes as well.

I would personally prefer the last option because its design is the cleanest one and it doesn't depend so much on OS-specific behavior. If your application consists of multiple processes started by the main process, then the main process may perform as the logging service as well and create *pipes* before spawning the child processes. If the processes are started separately, you can have a separate service that listens on a TCP/IP socket or (if your system supports it) a local domain socket.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the third method

Comment: @0xF1 I'll amend the text if you have further questions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. A file can be opened by several processes/programs simulatneously. Multiple processes/programs can read & write in a file simultaneously but the end result of writing in  the same file *at the same time* may be `undefined`. So it is better to use *locks*.

On Linux you can use: **[flocks](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock)**